# How to get the Description of a Magento\Catalog\Model\Product?

Tags: magento2, product-attribute, phtml

I'm in Magento2 and the `getDescription();` does not work.

I'm in the file `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` if that's relevant.

Comment: I want show description in additional div after tabs section on product page, how can i achieve this. Please help, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

In *Store > Attributes > Product > **Description** > Storefront Properties* set **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront** and **Used in Product Listing** to TRUE.

In your code `list.phtml` you can use:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $_product->getDescription() ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$productCollection = $this->helper('\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory');

$product = $productCollection->create()->load($id);

$description = $product->getDescription();
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow! you're answer does exactly what mine does.

Comment: You helped me with $description = $product->getDescription();

Answer (score 1):

It should work fine..

```
<?php echo $_product->getDescription(); ?>
```

Comment: please check out the accepted answer. you answer is redundant and is missing important parts

Answer (score 0):

See /vendor/magento/module-catalog/view/frontend/templates/product/view/description.phtml

```
/**
 * Product description template
 *
 * @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\View\Description
 */
?>
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
```

Comment: I already tried that. It's not working. If you have a look at the class of the object that returned by `getProduct` you will see, that there's no `getDescription()`

Comment: https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/develop/app/code/Magento/Catalog/Model/Product.php

Comment: getDescription should be a magic method, where the string after "get" is the attribute name

Comment: Doesn't care if its not in the object, thus not a magic getter. :)