# How to get products description and short description in products list page?

Tags: magento2, product

Can you please provide appropriate instruction for.

How can i get product description and short description in products list.phtml page.

Thanks

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109588/how-to-get-the-description-of-a-magento-catalog-model-product

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From `Stores` >> `Products` Attribute Section: 
Enable `Used in Product Listing` to `Yes` for both Short Description and Description Attribute.

For Short Decsription, in your theme `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml` file. You will find the below line. Set it as `Yes`

```
$showDescription = false;
```

For Description, use the below code in your theme `Magento_Catalog/templates/product/list.phtml`

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_helper->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description'); ?>
```