# Calling product description into custom module Magento 2

Tags: magento2, product

New to Magento 2 and hit a bit of a hurdle I can't seem to find the answer to.

I'm trying to add the product description into a custom module that's called inside of the product page.

I've tried copying the line inside of description.phtml

```
<?= /* @escapeNotVerified */ $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($block->getProduct(), $block->getProduct()->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
```

however I get a white page error with no error message when I try this.

I feel like I'm missing something pretty obvious.

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Can you please update your XML file content in question ? How you have added your template file in product detail page and all ?

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109588/how-to-get-the-description-of-a-magento-catalog-model-product/249647#249647](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109588/how-to-get-the-description-of-a-magento-catalog-model-product/249647#249647)

Comment: Take a look at my answer here: [https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109588/how-to-get-the-description-of-a-magento-catalog-model-product/249647#249647](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/109588/how-to-get-the-description-of-a-magento-catalog-model-product/249647#249647)

Answer (score 0):

In Store > Attributes > Product > **Description** > Storefront Properties set **Visible on Catalog Pages on Storefront** and **Used in Product Listing** to TRUE.

Then you can use in your `phtml` file:

```
<?php echo $this->helper('Magento\Catalog\Helper\Output')->productAttribute($_product, $_product->getDescription(), 'description') ?>
```

or

```
<?php echo $_product->getDescription() ?>
```

Let me know if this works for you.

Thank you.

Comment: Exception #0 (Exception): Notice: Undefined variable: _product

Comment: `$_product` is product object, which should be part of:
`\Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory`

Comment: Okay this is the part I'm missing, My block just extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template

Comment: is there documentation on how to make a module for Products descriptions etc?

Comment: can you explain what you are doing exactly. so I can tell u precisely what to do.

Comment: Are you able to make me a demo module that allows me to add a description to a phtml template for the product i'm viewing and put it up on Github for me to take a look at?

Answer (score 0):

In your custom module create a new Helper class that can return product data based on the product SKU something like

```
namespace CustomModule\Page\Helper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Product extends AbstractHelper
{
     protected $_productFactory;
     protected $_productRepository;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context $context,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductFactory $productFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->_productFactory = $productFactory;
        $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
    }

    public function getProductDataBySku($sku)
    {
        $product=$this->_productRepository->get($sku);
        return $product;
    }
}
```

You can access the product data in your template using

```
$_productHelper = $this->helper('CustomModule\Page\Helper\Product');
$_product=$_productHelper->getProductDataBySku('24-UG06');
$_description=$_product->getDescription();
```

Where 24-UG06 is the SKU.

Comment: I created this in a /Helper/ProductHelper.php once I did this I used <?php

                use \CompanyName\ModuleName\Helper\ProductHelper;

                class Product
                {
                    public function __construct(Product $helper)
                    {
                            $this->helper = $helper;
                    }
                    public function newFunction()
                    {
                            $this->helper->getStoreConfig();
                    }
                } ?>

I then tried to call the description however no luck!

Comment: I updated the answer for a helper class, the previous answer was for a block class. You did however say you wanted to access the data from a module not a template which is a bit confusing.